# Redirect all GnuPG output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, io-redirection, gpg

I'm doing key generation in a sort of batch mode with GnuPG (don't ask why):

```
echo -e 'addkey\n4\n2048\n120d\nsave' | gpg --command-fd 0 \
    --edit-key $master_key_id >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I still see all of the output here and I'd like to make it go away.

I'm trying to read their documentation to see which file descriptor they're writing to, but so far no success.

How can I redirect *ALL* of the output to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `...$master_key_id &> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

`gpg --batch` would work for that purpose.

Comment: Not for --edit-key. I don't think it accepts the --batch option.

Comment: It works for me (GnuPG 1.4.16 on Ubuntu 14.04).  Did you specify `--batch` as the first option?